# node: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6' library contains unsupported TLS

Tags: buildroot

When I run, node -v from terminal on arm machine. I get below error....

node: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6' library contains unsupported TLS
node: can't load library 'libstdc++.so.6'

I built the node with buildroot.
I copies all reqd libs in usr/lib also ....
And what error is showing on that lib, i copied that, libstdc++.so.6.0.19, as well.
and created symlink for libstdc++.so and libstdc++.so.6

and my output for ldd and node -v on AT91SAM9620 board =>

```
ldd /bin/node
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x4000e000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x40028000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x40082000)
libdl.so.0 => /lib/libdl.so.0 (0x4009f000)
librt.so.0 => /lib/librt.so.0 (0x400aa000)/bin/node:/usrlibstdc++.so.6
library contains unsupported TLS
libstdc++.so.6 => not found
libm.so.0 => /lib/libm.so.0 (0x400b3000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x400cb000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x400dd000)
libc.so.0 => /lib/libc.so.0 (0x400f7000)
ld-uClibc.so.0 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x40000000)
```

node -v

```
node: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6' library contains unsupported TLS
node: can't load library 'libstdc++.so.6'
```

Does it need anything else or any dependacies .....???
and all libs what it needs are present on board.

```
ls -ahl /usr/lib/ |grep libstdc++.so.6

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 22 10:15 libstdc++.so ->   
libstdc++.so.6.0.19
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 21 15:08 libstdc++.so.6 ->         
libstdc++.so.6.0.19
-rwx------ 1 root root 3.9M Jan 21 14:41 libstdc++.so.6.0.19
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2.4K Jan 21 14:56 libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
```

and ldd for that lib 
    ldd libstdc++.so.6.0.19

```
checking sub-depends for '/lib/libm.so.0'
checking sub-depends for '/lib/libc.so.0'
Segmentation fault
```

what is the segmentation fault is comming for ....???
what is this " library contains unsupported TLS" ...???
How can I solve this...???

How can I get out of this .....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you built libstdc++.so with an incompatible toolchain.

You should not need to copy any extra libraries. Buildroot will take care of all dependencies and install everything that is needed to your target rootfs. Just make sure that C++ support is enabled in the configuration and that you select the nodejs package.

Comment: Solved ..... !!! I was using the older version of c , g++ libs so that segmentation fault used to come ..... As you said buildroot takes all care of dependancies, after that I just replaced newer version of libs produced by buildroot ..... thanks a lot ....!!!